# Emit an event when a specific piece of state changes in vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a Vuex store with the following state:

```
state: {
    authed: false,
    id: false
}
```

Inside a component I want to watch for changes to the `authed` state and send an AJAX call to the server. It needs to be done in various components.

I tried using `store.watch()`, but that fires when either `id` or `authed` changes. I also noticed, it's different from `vm.$watch` in that you can't specify a property. When i tried to do this:

```
store.watch('authed', function(newValue, oldValue){
  //some code
});
```

I got this error:

`[vuex] store.watch only accepts a function.`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just set a getter for the `authed` state in your component and watch that local getter:

```
watch: {
  'authed': function () {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Or you can use ...

```js
let suscribe = store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
  console.log(mutation.type)
  console.log(mutation.payload)
})
// call suscribe() for unsuscribe
```

https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe